# Replacing a textbox in a Wordpress plugin (nova gallery) with wp_editor

Tags: php, wordpress, textarea, gallery, rich-text-editor

I haven't found a specific enough answer for my problem:

I have a plugin installed on my wordpress website, named Nova Gallery. This plugin has an option to add a description/caption to an image. The textbox where this is entered, however, isn't rich text at all, so the description to an image will look like a blob of text.

This is the code of nova-gallery-options.php:

```
<label class="main">Caption:</label>
<textarea name="<?php echo $itemNamePrefix;?>itemCaption<?php echo $itemNameSuffix; ?>[]"><?php echo stripcslashes( esc_textarea( $fields['itemCaption'][$i] ) ); ?></textarea>
```

My question is: where do I 'insert' wp_editor in this?

```
<?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() ); ?>
```

Shunarjuna, at http://wordpress.org/support/topic/convert-text-area-into-wp-editor transformed his textarea:

```
<textarea name="post_content"><?php echo esc_textarea( $listing->post_content ); ?></textarea>
```

into:

```
<?php wp_editor( $listing->post_content, 'listingeditor', $settings = array('textarea_name' => post_content) ); ?>
```

Maybe Shunarjuna's solution will aid in solving my problem?

Thanks in advance! Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: `<?php wp_editor( stripcslashes( esc_textarea( $fields['itemCaption'][$i] ) ), $editor_id, $settings = array() ); ?>`

Comment: While this does insert an 'add media' button and 2 buttons: 'visual' and 'text', this breaks the functionality of the editor. 

It looks like this now:
[link]http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20131228-h5g6-7kb

The input renders invisible as well.
Thanks for your help!